# How to give task to multiple users by filling same form in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-7, laravel-8

i make a task manager for practice. I have 1 query that how can i assign task to multiple users by filling 1 form

This is my TaskController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'staff_id' => 'required',
        'task' => 'required',
        'done_at' => 'sometimes',
    ]);

    $task = Task::create([
        'staff_id' => $request->input('staff_id'),
        'task' => $request->input('task'),
        'done_at' => $request->input('done_at'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('tasks.index')->withSuccess('Done');
}
public function complete($id)
{
    $task = Task::find($id);
    if ($task->done_at !== null) {
        $task->done_at = null;

        $task->save();
    } else {
        $task->done_at = now();

        $task->save();
}
```

This is my task model the task model having relation with another table name staffs

```
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'staff_id',
    'task',
];

public function staff()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Staff::class);
}
```

This is my create page where there is a form

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('tasks.store')}}">
        @csrf
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Staff Name : </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="staff_id" id="staff_id">
                            <option value="">Select One</option>
                            @foreach ($staffs as $staff)

                                <option value="{{ $staff->id }}">{{ $staff->name }}</option>

                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Task : </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="task" class="form-control"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Done At :</td>
                    <td><input type="time" name="done_at" class="form-control"></td>
                </tr>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">Submit</button></td>
        </table>
    </form>
```

and this is my tasks table and this is my tasks table and this is my tasks table and this is my tasks table.

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->bigInteger('staff_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('task')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('done_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to Add `Foreachloop` For Multiple Users

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'staff_id' => 'required',
            'task' => 'required',
            'done_at' => 'sometimes',
        ]);
    

foreach($request->staff_id as $staff_ID){

 $task = Task::create([
            'staff_id' => $staff_ID,
            'task' => $request->input('task'),
            'done_at' => $request->input('done_at'),
        ]);

}
       
    
        return redirect()->route('tasks.index')->withSuccess('Done');
    }
```

Comment: I think the structure of his code doesn't support that. If you looked at the view he sends only one id 
the model relationship in the model isn't structured well 
I think these stuff need to be changed

Answer (score 0):

you need to change some things in some files

the Task model

you need to change the relationship between tasks and staff to many to many and add the pivot table for that see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

```
    public function staff()
{
    return $this->belongToMany(Staff::class);
}
```

then in the controller, you need to attach the task you created with an array of staff ids like so

```
$task = Task::create([
        'task' => $request->input('task'),
        'done_at' => $request->input('done_at'),
    ]);
$task->staff()->attach($request->input('staff_id'))
```

and finally, at the view, you need to send an array of staff id's, you can do so by multiple select using js library like select2 or something see [docs](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)